# How to copy the fzf query to the command line?

Tags: fuzzy-search, fzf

I'm wondering if there is a way to make the fuzzy search tool "fzf" copy the query to the command line to be able to edit it, in case there is no satisfactory match.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a keybinding which copies the selected file's path(or contents of that file) to your clipboard

```
--bind 'ctrl-y:execute(readlink -f {} | xclip -selection clipboard)'
```

```
--bind 'ctrl-alt-y:execute-silent(xclip -selection clipboard {})'
```

Add these lines in your `.bashrc` inside `export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="  "`.
A user suggested this method on fzf's github repo:
[Its Possible Copy To Clipboard ?](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2323)